# Syntax Errors when implementing binary search tree (C)

Tags: c, function, struct, syntax-error, binary-tree

I've been working on implementing a binary search tree in C for a homework assignment in my programming class. After writing this much of the code and compiling in Visual Studio 2010, I get numerous errors.

I have looked online for people who have gotten similar errors and none of them are close enough for me to figure out what the problem might be.

Here is the code:

```
/*This code will implement a binary search tree based on 20
user-inputed integers. It will then implement a search,
insert, delete, and traverse function. */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ARRSIZE 20

/*------ TYPE DEFINITIONS ------*/

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

typedef struct tree
{
    int count;
    node* root;
};

/*------ FUNCTION DECLARTATIONS ------*/

void InitializeTree (tree* ptree);
int insert (int data, tree* ptree);
void place (node* root, node* new_node);

/*------ MAIN FUNCTION ------*/

int main (void)
{
    int i, check, arr[ARRSIZE];
    tree BST;

    InitializeTree(&BST);

    printf("Enter 20 integers for a list.\n");

    for(i=0; i<ARRSIZE; i++)
    {
        printf("Integer %d:\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        check = insert(arr[i], &BST);
        if(check == 0)
        {
            printf("Error in creating node.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/*
*
* ADDITIONAL FUNCTIONS
*
*/

/*------ CREATION FUNCTIONS ------*/

void InitializeTree (tree* ptree)
{
    ptree = (tree*) malloc(sizeof(tree));
    ptree->count = 0;
}

int insert (int data, tree* ptree)
{
    node* new_node;

    new_node = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(new_node == NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't create a node.\n");
        return 0;
    }
        new_node->data = data;

    ptree->count++;

    if(ptree->root == NULL)
    {
        ptree->root = new_node;
    }

    else
    {
        place(ptree->root, new_node);
    }
    return 1;

}

void place (node* root, node* new_node)
{
    if(new_node->data < root->data)
    {
        if(root->left == NULL)
        {
            root->left = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            place(root->left, new_node);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(root->right == NULL)
        {
            root->right = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
        place(root->right, new_node;
        }
    }
}
```

The errors look like this:

```
1>bin-tree.c(16): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'node'
1>bin-tree.c(17): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(18): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>bin-tree.c(23): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'node'
1>bin-tree.c(24): error C2059: syntax error : '}'
1>bin-tree.c(28): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(28): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(28): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>bin-tree.c(29): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(29): error C2081: 'tree' : name in formal parameter list illegal
1>bin-tree.c(29): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(29): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>bin-tree.c(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(30): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(30): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>bin-tree.c(37): error C2065: 'tree' : undeclared identifier
1>bin-tree.c(37): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'BST'
1>bin-tree.c(37): error C2065: 'BST' : undeclared identifier
1>bin-tree.c(39): warning C4013: 'InitializeTree' undefined; assuming extern returning int
1>bin-tree.c(39): error C2065: 'BST' : undeclared identifier
1>bin-tree.c(47): warning C4013: 'insert' undefined; assuming extern returning int
1>bin-tree.c(47): error C2065: 'BST' : undeclared identifier
1>bin-tree.c(66): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(66): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(66): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>bin-tree.c(67): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'ptree'
1>bin-tree.c(72): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(72): error C2081: 'tree' : name in formal parameter list illegal
1>bin-tree.c(72): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(72): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>bin-tree.c(73): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'ptree'
1>bin-tree.c(99): error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(99): error C2143: syntax error : missing '{' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(99): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>bin-tree.c(99): error C2059: syntax error : ')'
1>bin-tree.c(100): error C2054: expected '(' to follow 'new_node'
```

Does anyone know what might be causing such numerous errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your typedefs from:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};

typedef struct tree
{
    int count;
    node* root;
};
```

to:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;   // <<<
    struct node* right;  // <<<
} node;                  // <<<

typedef struct tree
{
    int count;
    node* root;
} tree;                  // <<<
```

Also as noted by @Binayaka, you have a missing bracket - change

```
    place(root->right, new_node;
```

to:

```
    place(root->right, new_node);
```

Comment: Missing Parenthesis on Original Code, line 118. Change it along with the given answer :)

Comment: No, you are absolutely right. Thanks, I'm still relatively new at programming and little errors get me all the time.

Comment: @Zelmec: no problem - the "take home message" here is that attention to detail is absolutely crucial when it comes to programming...

Comment: I forgot to specify in the definitions that they were struct node*s.

Thanks for all the help!